# Is this proof correct, $\lvert x \rvert=0$ iff $x=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, absolute-value

I looking for comments and corrections on my proof. I'm also unsure if the second case is correct.

> For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have:
>
> $\lvert x\rvert \geq 0$, and $\lvert x \rvert=0$ if and only if $x=0$.

I have three cases:

1. For $x>0$, the absolute value $\lvert x\rvert=x$ is greater than zero, so $x \neq 0$. This case not true according to the theorem.
2. For $x<0$, we have $\lvert x\rvert =-x>0$, which is less than zero, so $x<0$. This case not true according to the theorem.
3. For $x=0$, we have $\lvert x\rvert=0$, according to the theorem. Therefore the theorem is true only for $x=0$.

Thanks!

Comment: In the case of $n > 1$, I assume $0$ stands for the zero vector? Also, why is the condition $a \in \mathbb{R}$ in the statement? $a$ is not used anywhere for anything - what is $a$ supposed to be?

Comment: either  $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a typo, or your proofs make no sense. If $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then you cannot say $x>0$, because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not ordered like $\mathbb{R}$ is

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee It was a typo.

Comment: @user160738 It was a typo, so $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ all you need is $-|x| \le x \le |x|\,$.

Comment: For a proof to make sense, you must give a definition of the absolute value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition about : $a = b \iff | a − b| &lt; \epsilon$, for every $\epsilon &gt; 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436553/intuition-about-a-b-iff-a-%e2%88%92-b-epsilon-for-every-epsilon-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the absolute value is defined as

$$|x|:=\begin{cases}x>0\to x\\x=0\to0\\x<0\to-x\end{cases},$$

you can say
$$|x|\ge0\iff (x>0\land x\ge0)\lor(x=0\land 0\ge0)\lor(x<0\land-x\ge0)\\\iff x>0\lor x=0\lor x<0\iff\text{true}.$$
$$|x|=0\iff (x>0\land x=0)\lor(x=0\land 0=0)\lor(x<0\land-x=0)\\\iff x=0\lor x=0\lor x=0\iff x=0.$$

If it is defined as

$$|x|:=\begin{cases}x\ge0\to x\\x\le0\to-x\end{cases},$$

you can say

$$|x|\ge0\iff (x\ge0\land x\ge0)\lor(x\le0\land-x\ge0)\iff x\ge0\lor x\le 0\iff\text{true}.$$
$$|x|=0\iff (x\ge0\land x=0)\lor(x\le0\land-x=0)\\\iff x=0\lor x=0\iff x=0.$$

If it is defined as

$$|x|:=\sqrt{x^2},$$ then

$$\sqrt{x^2}\ge0$$ by definition of the square root, and by squaring, then solving the quadratic equation

$$\sqrt{x^2}=0\iff x^2=0^2=0\iff x=0.$$

Comment: Thanks! Suppose I instead have $|x|\ge x$, is the proof similar? I.e. with your first definition: $(x>0\land x\ge x)\lor(x=0\land 0\ge x)\lor(x<0\land-x\ge x)\\ \iff x>0\lor x=0\lor x<0\iff\text{true}.$

Comment: @JDoeDoe: absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem should be interpreted as

> For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have:
>   $(\lvert x\rvert \geq 0$) and ($\lvert x \rvert=0$ if and only if $x=0$).

With this in mind, the theorem should be straightforward to prove using your casework.